# How to calculate time in string type from array

Tags: postgresql

There is a column called `period` in table `Trip` in my PostgreSql DB,

An example of `period` in one row looks like:

```
["2020-04-14 00:29:11+00","2020-04-14 02:27:53+00"]
```

here array member is time in string type.

I want to calculate how many seconds between these two time, this is my query:

```
select (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (tp."period")[1])-EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM tp."period"[0])) from "Trip" tp
```

But I get ERROR:

```
/* ERROR:  cannot subscript type tstzrange because it is not an array */
```

Could you please help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a range, not an array. To access the bounds of a range use `lower()` (for the lower bound) and `upper()` (for the upper bound).

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM upper(tp.period)) - extract(epoch FROM lower(tp.period))
       FROM "Trip" tp;
```